# How can I write this notation in latex?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I was wondering if somebody could tell me how to write this notation in latex?

[image]

Comment: That's `\leftrightarroweq` from the `stmaryrd` package.

Comment: @campa Thanks very much for the comment. How can I add this package?

Comment: @M.Ramana Add `\usepackage{stmaryrd}` to your document. Then you can use `\leftrightarroweq`

Comment: @egreg It worked. I appreciate it.